# Cambio de tipo de dato del valor en diccionario de python

Tags: python

tengo esta pieza de código en la que no consigo modificar el valor de este diccionario ya que conlleva u  cambio de tipo de dato de integer a string ¿alguna sugernecia?

```
def calificar_alumno(notas):
        for clave, valor in notas.items():
            if valor>=0 and valor<3:
                valor = "muy mal"
            if valor>=3 and valor<5:
                valor = "insuficiente"
            if valor>=5 and valor<6:
                valor = "suficiente"
            if valor>=6 and valor<7:
                valor = "bien"
            if valor>=7 and valor<9:
                valor = "notable"
            if valor>=9 and valor<10:
                valor = "sobresaliente"
        return print(notas)
    notas = {}
    continuar = True
    while continuar == True:
        asignatura = input("Introduce la asignatura: ")
        nota = int(input("Introduce la nota de la asignatura: "))
        notas[asignatura] = nota
        continuar = input("¿desea continuar añadiendo?(si/no): ")
        if continuar == "si":
            continuar = True
        else:
            continuar = False
    
    calificar_alumno(notas)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que arreglar en tu código.

De entrada, la indentación del código que aparece en la pregunta no es correcta, aunque supongo que eso es debido a un copia-pega incorrecto. Entiendo que el cuerpo de la función `calificar_alumno()` llega sólo hasta el `return` y que todo lo que va después, aunque en tu pregunta aparece indentado y por tanto dentro de la función, iría en realidad desindentado y afuera.

Pero una vez arreglada la indentación, al ejecutar tu código efectivamente se llega a un punto en el que aparece el error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

que probablemente es el que te ha hecho pensar que hay un problema por asignar una cadena en una variable que antes era entera.

En realidad **no hay ningún problema** por cambiar el tipo de una variable, ya que en python el tipado es dinámico. El problema viene por otra razón. Por ejemplo observa este fragmento de tu código e imagina que la nota que estás procesando tiene `valor` 2:

```
        if valor>=0 and valor<3:
            valor = "muy mal"
        if valor>=3 and valor<5:
            valor = "insuficiente"
```

Al ser `valor` 2, se entra por el primer `if`, por lo que se le asigna a `valor` la cadena `"muy mal"`. Esa asignación no causa problemas. Pero el problema surge en el siguiente `if` en el que comparas `valor >= 3`. Es esta comparación la que ya no puede hacerse debido a que `valor` ahora es `"muy mal"` que no puede compararse con 3.

La solución es simple. Una vez se ha entrado por un `if` ya no hay que mirar el resto de casos, lo que se arregla cambiando los restantes `if` por `elif`.

De paso vamos a arreglar un par de cosas más:

- Las funciones no deberían imprimir nada, sino retornar un resultado (en este caso retornar `notas`). Tu función tiene un `return print()` pero eso solo retorna el valor devuelto por `print()` que es siempre `None` (y no lo que `print()` imprime). Mejor dejar que sea el programa principal quien imprima el resultado.
- El cambiar `valor` no altera el diccionario. Para alterar el diccionario tienes que asignar el resultado en `notas[clave]`
- Si vamos a alterar directamente el diccionario, no necesitamos que la función retorne nada, ya que la propia variable `notas` del programa principal resultará alterada.

Con estas consideraciones el código queda así:

```py
# @title modificar diccionario de notas

def calificar_alumno(notas):
    for clave, valor in notas.items():
        if valor>=0 and valor<3:
            valor = "muy mal"
        elif valor>=3 and valor<5:
            valor = "insuficiente"
        elif valor>=5 and valor<6:
            valor = "suficiente"
        elif valor>=6 and valor<7:
            valor = "bien"
        elif valor>=7 and valor<9:
            valor = "notable"
        elif valor>=9 and valor<10:
            valor = "sobresaliente"
        notas[clave] = valor   # Modificar el diccionario

notas = {}
continuar = True
while continuar == True:
    asignatura = input("Introduce la asignatura: ")
    nota = int(input("Introduce la nota de la asignatura: "))
    notas[asignatura] = nota
    continuar = input("¿desea continuar añadiendo?(si/no): ")
    if continuar == "si":
        continuar = True
    else:
        continuar = False

calificar_alumno(notas)
print(notas)
```

## Otra versión

En general no es muy buena idea que una función modifique el parámetro que ha recibido, para causar "efectos secundarios" en el programa que la llamó (es decir, que el programa principal obtenga su diccionario `notas` modificado). Este estilo de programación puede llevar a bugs difíciles de encontrar.

Es mejor si la función en vez de modificar el diccionario que recibe como parámetro construye otro con la traducción de notas a texto.

Esto puede ser tan simple como:

```
def calificar_alumno(notas):
  return { clave: nota_a_texto(nota) for clave, nota in notas.items()}
```

en donde estoy haciendo uso de la sintaxis *dictionary comprehension* para crear un diccionario directamente iterando por otro, y estoy suponiendo que hay una función `nota_a_texto()` que recibe una nota (por ejmeplo 3) y retorna su representación como texto (por ejemplo "insuficiente"). Esta función puede ser la que aparece en la respuesta de @CandidMoe.

Por ofrecer aún más opciones, seguidamente muestro otra forma de programar una función `nota_a_texto()` que en lugar de tener una serie de `if` ... `elif`, tiene la información necesaria para la conversión en una lista e itera por ella.

```
def nota_a_texto(nota):
  limites = ((0, "muy mal"),
             (3, "insuficiente"),
             (5, "suficiente"),
             (6, "bien"),
             (7, "notable"),
             (9, "sobresaliente"))
  for umbral, calificacion in limites:
    if nota >= umbral:
       texto = calificacion
    else:
      break
  return texto
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
notas = {"Mate": 2, "Lengua": 3, "TIC": 10, "Fisica": 5.5}
result = calificar_alumno(notas)
print(result)
```

---

```
{'Mate': 'muy mal', 'Lengua': 'insuficiente', 'TIC': 'sobresaliente', 'Fisica': 'suficiente'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Craso error:

```
    if valor >= 0 and valor < 3:
        valor = "muy mal"
    if valor >= 3 and valor < 5:
        valor = "insuficiente"
```

Digamos que `valor = 2`. En el primer `if` reasignas `valor` con un string ("muy mal"). En el segundo `if` intentas comparar `valor`, que hora tiene un string, contra valores enteros. Eso no funciona.

En el segundo `if` no tiene objeto compara `valor >= 3`. Si fuera menor que 3, habría caido en el `if` anterior. Puedo eliminar todas las comparaciones del tipo `>=` en el segundo y siguientes `if`

```
    if valor >= 0 and valor < 3:
        valor = "muy mal"
    elif valor < 5:
        valor = "insuficiente"
```

Otro falla es

```
return print(notas)
```

Primero, `print` no retorna nada y, en cualquier caso, tampoco estás usando el valor retornado.

Es mala idea hacer/entrada salida dentro de funciones, pues te impide reutilizarlas en otros contextos. Lo conveniente es simplemente devolver un string con el resultado y que el llamante vea que hace con él.

Tampoco tiene lógica la iteración:

```
for clave, valor in notas.items():
```

pues estas recorriendo y procesando múltiples veces `valor`, pero solo retornas el último resultado.

Dado que la definición obvia de la función es entregar un texto asociado a una nota, la función debería quedar así:

```
def calificar_alumno(valor):

        if valor < 3:
            valor = "muy mal"
        elif valor < 5:
            valor = "insuficiente"
        elif valor < 6:
            valor = "suficiente"
        elif valor < 7:
            valor = "bien"
        elif valor < 9:
            valor = "notable"
        elif valor < 10:
            valor = "sobresaliente"
        else:
            valor = "error"

    return valor
```

#### Demo

El programa principal también se puede reducir, quedando asi:

```
def calificar_alumno(valor):
    if valor < 3:
        valor = "muy mal"
    elif valor < 5:
        valor = "insuficiente"
    elif valor < 6:
        valor = "suficiente"
    elif valor < 7:
        valor = "bien"
    elif valor < 9:
        valor = "notable"
    elif valor < 10:
        valor = "sobresaliente"
    else:
        valor = "error"

    return valor


notas = {}
continuar = "si"
while continuar == "si":
    asignatura = input("Introduce la asignatura: ")
    notas[asignatura] = int(input("Introduce la nota de la asignatura: "))
    continuar = input("¿desea continuar añadiendo?(si/no): ").lower()
    
print()
for clave, valor in notas.items():
    print("Materia", clave, "nota", calificar_alumno(valor))
```

produce:

```
Introduce la asignatura: Mat
Introduce la nota de la asignatura: 5
¿desea continuar añadiendo?(si/no): si
Introduce la asignatura: Lit
Introduce la nota de la asignatura: 6
¿desea continuar añadiendo?(si/no): no

Materia Mat nota suficiente
Materia Lit nota bien
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra alternativa si las notas fuesen números enteros (sin decimales) sería crear un diccionario con los diez valores (Ya que no son muchos y no cambian) y acceder a ellos por clave.

```
NOTAS = {0:"muy mal", 1:"muy mal", 2:"muy mal", 3:"insuficiente", 4:"insuficiente", 5: "suficiente", 6:"bien", 7:"bien", 8:"notable", 9:"sobresaliente", 10:"sobresaliente"}

def calificar_alumno(valor):
    try:
        return NOTAS[valor]
    except KeyError:
        print('[ERROR] Solo numeros enteros del 0 al 10')
```

De esta forma simplificas mucho la función y te ahorras ese nido de "if" que no es muy pythonico. Accedes al diccionario por clave y con el `try/except` capturas cualquier valor de llave que no exista y devuelves un mensaje de error.

Aparte al crear el diccionario fuera de la función puedes reutilizarlo en cualquier otra parte y si lo modificas no tienes que buscar y cambiar todo tu código donde antes usabas `if`.

## ALTERNATIVA CON SOPORTE DECIMAL

Con una pequeña modificación puedes evaluar también decimales:

```
def calificar_alumno(valor):
    
    if not isinstance(valor, (int, float)):
        raise TypeError("[ERROR] Solo numeros enteros o con decimales")
    if 0 > valor or valor > 10:
        raise ValueError("[ERROR] Solo números entre 0 y 10")

    lista_notas = NOTAS.keys()
    for nota in lista_notas:
        if 0 < nota >= valor:
            return NOTAS[nota]
```

Lo que haces es comprobar si el valor de entrada de la función es de tipo `int` o `float` y falla si es otra cosa con un TypeError. Luego comprueba si el número está dentro del margen 0 y 10 y si todo está correcto recorre la lista de valores numéricos del diccionario de notas y devuelve el primer resultado que sea igual o mayor al valor de la nota de entrada.